# Delphi 7 IDE - How to disable color for active line?

Tags: delphi, ide

I have changed my IDE color schema few times to and from and now noticed to have active line always coloured. I have searched in editor options > color > something like highlight line, like in XE but didnt find anything thah would mach. Can anyone help?!

Comment: Do you have any third party IDE enhancements like CNPack or Castalia?

Comment: That is a good clue, I have CnPack installed. I will look for it there then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have CNPack installed you need to go to CNPack..IDE Enhancement Settings..Source Highlight Settings and uncheck Enable Background Highlight Current Line (Delphi 7 Below Only)

Comment: Update: Using version 1.2.8.1150 2023.11.01 you can found in 'Souce Higlight Enhancements' > Settings > 'Enabled Background Highlight Current Line'